Symbolicate NDK crash log in Android
I've got my hands on an android native crash log that looks like this:
0x7829abbf20 0x7829a73000 + 298784 (libc.so)
0x7829abc8a8 0x7829a73000 + 301224 (libc.so)
0x7829abcda4 0x7829a73000 + 302500 (libc.so)
0x7829abe838 0x7829a73000 + 309304 (libc.so)
0x7195763ec4 0x719561e000 + 1334980 (libmyLibrary.so)
0x719575b0c0 0x719561e000 + 1298624 (libmyLibrary.so)
0x71957316b8 0x719561e000 + 1128120 (libmyLibrary.so)
0x719573b3b8 0x719561e000 + 1168312 (libmyLibrary.so)
0x7195717140 0x719561e000 + 1020224 (libmyLibrary.so)

And I'm not able to decode the crash log.
I already know how to symbolize some crash logs that look like the one described in the official android web page:
I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 351, tid: 351  >>> /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0d9f00d8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 0000af88  r1 0000a008  r2 baadf00d  r3 0d9f00d8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000004  r5 0000a008  r6 0000af88  r7 00013c44
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip 0000959c  sp be956cc8  lr 00008403  pc 0000841e  cpsr 60000030
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 0000841e  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 000083fe  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 000083f6  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #03  pc 000191ac  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #04  pc 000083ea  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #05  pc 00008458  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #06  pc 0000d362  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):

How can I symbolize a crash log like the one I got?
Thanks
